# I'm getting a timeout error and topology error what to do?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

i want to start a local database using mongodb. so I started creating a database using native nodejs driver. but when i run the server then there  is a problem that exits. please guide me. thank you

Connection code:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb'); // Connection URI
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'; // Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect(); // Establish and verify connection
    await client.db('fruitsDB').command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

> MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\mskga\Desktop\fruitsproject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:284:38)
>
> ```
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {   reason: TopologyDescription {
> type: 'Unknown',
> servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
> stale: false,
> compatible: true,
> heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
> localThresholdMS: 15,
> setName: null,
> maxElectionId: null,
> maxSetVersion: null,
> commonWireVersion: 0,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null   },   code: undefined,   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {} }
> ```

this is the error that I'm getting so please tell me what is the error exactly and how to rectify it

Comment: Can you post the code where you handle the database connection?

Comment: const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
// Connection URI
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
    await client.connect();
    // Establish and verify connection
    await client.db("fruitsDB").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

Comment: Did you start the `mongod` process locally?

Comment: yes i started the mongod locally but still I'm getting  an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the host value from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

```js
const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

Comment: thanks @mostafa fakhraei. it worked successfully